# How do I scrape text within strong tag and normal text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I have list of li tag and in each li tag has some text with strong tag and normal text
Xpath for //*[@id="main"]/li[1]/strong 
How do i get normal text, if i take xpath of li tag then it will scrape whole text, is there any way to get separate text

```
<li>
<strong>Heading</strong>
: Sample paragraph to get the text from here.
</li>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use BeautifulSoup? Or does it have to be XPath?

Comment: try  your_browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="main"]/li[1]").text

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `<li>` text and remove the `<strong>` text from it

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/li[1]')
all_text = element.text
element = element.find_element_by_xpath('./strong')
text = all_text.replace(element.text, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium Induce `JavaScript` Executor and get the `lastChild` of the node.

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/li[1]')))
```

Answer (score -1):

To scrape the normal text you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and as the desired node is a *text node* you can use `execute_script()` method along with the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[./strong[text()='Heading']]")))))
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li/strong[text()='Heading']/..")))))
  ```